# iPad layout: creating "Find my Friends" layout

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to create something like the "Find my Friends" app, in terms of how all the views are layed out, but can't figure out how it's done:

- It seems to be a UITabBarContrller but mixed with UISplitViewControllers within each tab. I thought that wasn't possible / advisable?
- How do you get these rounded edges for each view within each split-view (if they are, indeed, splitviews)
- How do they space the views from the borders and from each other? When I create a simple SplitViewController, both the master-detail views are fully embedded in their views with no margins against each other, or against the screen boundary.
- How do you get the stiched leather background to fit so well, behind all the views?

I would love to know how this is done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a UISplitViewController, just a custom view that is embedded multiple times under a UITabBarController with some different parameters.

For the rest of the questions, I don't think the stitched leather is a background. I think they may be putting that on top of the views with the rounded corners and shadows built into the image, and with transparency where the views fit in. The other option is just setting the UIViews to have rounded corners using the CALayer property.

In terms of the UIView spacing, you can just set that in the XIB/storyboard.